# Update React component every second

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been playing around with React and have the following time component that just renders `Date.now()` to the screen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TimeComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { time: Date.now() };
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div> { this.state.time } </div>
    );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("TimeComponent Mounted...")
  }
}

export default TimeComponent;
```

What would be the best way to get this component to update every second to re-draw the time from a React perspective?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

You need to use `setInterval` to trigger the change, but you also need to clear the timer when the component unmounts to prevent it leaving errors and leaking memory:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState({ time: Date.now() }), 1000);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Comment: If you would like a library that encapsulates this kind of thing, I made [`react-interval-rerender`](https://github.com/jcoreio/react-interval-rerender)

Comment: I added my setInterval method in my constructor and that worked better.

Answer (score 133):

@Waisky suggested:

> You need to use `setInterval` to trigger the change, but you also need to clear the timer when the component unmounts to prevent it leaving errors and leaking memory:

If you'd like to do the same thing, using Hooks:

```js
const [time, setTime] = useState(Date.now());

useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => setTime(Date.now()), 1000);
  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
  };
}, []);
```

**Regarding the comments:**

You don't need to pass anything inside `[]`. If you pass `time` in the brackets, it means run the effect every time the value of `time` changes, i.e., it invokes a new `setInterval` every time, `time` changes, which is not what we're looking for. We want to only invoke `setInterval` once when the component gets mounted and then `setInterval` calls `setTime(Date.now())` every 1000 seconds. Finally, we invoke `clearInterval` when the component is unmounted.

Note that the component gets updated, based on how you've used `time` in it, every time the value of `time` changes. That has nothing to do with putting `time` in `[]` of `useEffect`.

Comment: Why did you pass an empty array (`[]`) as second argument to `useEffect`?

Comment: The [React documentation on the effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) tells us: “If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument.” But OP wants the effect to run every second, i.e. reoccurring, i.e. not just once.

Comment: The difference I noticed if you pass in [time] in the array, it will create and destroy the component every interval. If you pass the empty array [], it will keep refreshing the component and only unmount it when you leave the page. But, in either case, to get it to work, I had to add key={time} or key={Date.now()} to get it to actually rerender.

Comment: If `time` is passed as a prop to a child component, that component will re-render whenever time changes. Or you can trigger a different effect with `[time]` as the second argument, and that effect will fire every time `time` gets a new value. The useEffect that sets the interval should have an empty array as the second argument, because it isn't updating, only setting/clearing the interval.

Answer (score 97):

The following code is a modified example from React.js website.

Original code is available here: https://reactjs.org/#a-simple-component

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      seconds: parseInt(props.startTimeInSeconds, 10) || 0
    };
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      seconds: state.seconds + 1
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  formatTime(secs) {
    let hours   = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    let minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60) % 60;
    let seconds = secs % 60;
    return [hours, minutes, seconds]
        .map(v => ('' + v).padStart(2, '0'))
        .filter((v,i) => v !== '00' || i > 0)
        .join(':');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Timer: {this.formatTime(this.state.seconds)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Timer startTimeInSeconds="300" />,
  document.getElementById('timer-example')
);
```

Comment: I for some reason get this.updater.enqueueSetState is not a function error when using this approach. setInterval callback is properly bound to the component this.

Comment: For idiots like me: don't name timer `updater` because it ruins update cycle

Comment: With ES6 I need to change one line like this.interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this),1000);

Comment: Can you add the link to the url that references? Thanks~

Comment: I added a formatting method and a "constructor" property for more robustness.

Answer (score 9):

In the component's `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, you can set an interval to call a function which updates the state.

```
 componentDidMount() {
      setInterval(() => this.setState({ time: Date.now()}), 1000)
 }
```

Comment: Correct, but as the top answer suggests, remember to clear the time to avoid memory leak:

componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}

Answer (score 5):

```
class ShowDateTime extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        curTime : null
      }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      setInterval( () => {
        this.setState({
          curTime : new Date().toLocaleString()
        })
      },1000)
    }
   render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <h2>{this.state.curTime}</h2>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

i myself like `setTimeout` more that `setInterval` but didn't find a solution in class based component .you could use sth like this in class based components:

## class based component and setInterval:

```js
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date()
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( 
  <Clock / > ,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app" />
```

## function based component and setInterval:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-diffie-wsu1t?file=/src/index.js

## function based component and setTimeout:

https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-lovelace-xw46p

Answer (score 0):

So you were on the right track. Inside your `componentDidMount()` you could have finished the job by implementing `setInterval()` to trigger the change, but remember the way to update a components state is via `setState()`, so inside your `componentDidMount()` you could have done this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  setInterval(() => {
   this.setState({time: Date.now()})    
  }, 1000)
}
```

Also, you use `Date.now()` which works, with the `componentDidMount()` implementation I offered above, but you will get a long set of nasty numbers updating that is not human readable, but it is technically the time updating every second in milliseconds since January 1, 1970, but we want to make this time readable to how we humans read time, so in addition to learning and implementing `setInterval` you want to learn about `new Date()` and `toLocaleTimeString()` and you would implement it like so:

```
class TimeComponent extends Component {
  state = { time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString() };
}

componentDidMount() {
  setInterval(() => {
   this.setState({ time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString() })    
  }, 1000)
}
```

Notice I also removed the `constructor()` function, you do not necessarily need it, my refactor is 100% equivalent to initializing site with the `constructor()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Owing to changes in React V16 where componentWillReceiveProps() has been deprecated, this is the methodology that I use for updating a component.
Notice that the below example is in Typescript and uses the static getDerivedStateFromProps method to get the initial state and updated state whenever the Props are updated.

```
    class SomeClass extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps: Readonly<Props>): Partial<State> | null {
    return {
      time: nextProps.time
    };
  }

  timerInterval: any;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerInterval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({ time: this.props.time });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.time}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented even with the setTimeout instead of setInterval. As the useState re-renders the component, it will call the setTimeout again and again.
Here is my sample component which update the timer in every second. Also, Please let me know if I am making any mistake here.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Footer() {
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState((new Date()).getSeconds());

    function GetTime() {
        setSeconds((new Date()).getSeconds());
        console.count(seconds);
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Footer Rendered");
        GetTime();
    }, 1000);

    return (
        <footer>
            <h2>Test Footer</h2>
            <p>Copyright &copy; {seconds}</p>
        </footer>
    )
}
```