# How can I clear Interval in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, setinterval

I am using setInterval on react redux.
Below is my function.

FileAction.js

```
export const SetPath = ({ path, location }) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        let interval;
        if (pre_path === path) {
            interval = setInterval(() => {
                handler(path);
            }, 3000);
        } else {
            pre_path = path;
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        const handler = async (pth) => {
            const mtime = await axios.post('/api/file', { data: pth });
            dispatch({
                type: GET_EVENT,
                payload: { time: mtime, position: location }
            });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_ERROR
        });
    }
};
```

**What I would like to do is when I call `SetPath` function, it have to fetch data from `api/file` every 3 secs.**

But now when I pass another path to `SetPath` function, it dulicate interval.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch data automatically every minute in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59631152/how-to-fetch-data-automatically-every-minute-in-react)

Comment: use a ref to store the interval since you need it to persist between renders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the `interval` variable *inside* `setPath` function, therefore the variable will be reinitialized everytime `setPath` is executed. Try defining it *outside* the function. You may need to use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) in order to not lose the variable when a re-render occurs.

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful.
I define `interval` variable outside of function.